# What is the best way to store a reference to an arbitrary class inside an enum constant using the least memory on initialization as possible?

Tags: java, memory, enums

I have been working with enums and in a specific project where get an input as a String, and have a list of possible Strings(Commands) that each do something.

Each command has its own class that implements an interface, making sure they have a method with the same name that starts the execution and does whatever it has to.

The command list is stored in an `enum`, with each enum constant name being the actual `String` that can call the method, using some methods to get the enum value from string.

The way I reach and invoke the method from the enum is by making a reference to the actual class from the command itself as a parameter in the enum constant:

```
COMMAND(Command.class);
```

And then in the constructor I pass that class to a variable `Class<?>` and only create an instance of that object on request using a method:

```
public Object getInstance() {
    try{
        return this.cls.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch {
      //exceptions   
      }
    }
```

And from that I get the `Method` using 
`getInstance().getClass().getDeclaredMethod("Method_Name");`
And only invoke the method when necessary

Is this the best way to store those references, or is this a waste of memory?

Comment: References don't use a lot of memory, but you don't need all this convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why memory is your concern, but you can make it simpler without reflection.

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
enum YourEnum {
  COMMAND1(Command1::new),
  COMMAND2(Command2::new);

  private final Supplier<? extends Command> commandSupplier;

}
```

assuming that

```
interface Command {}
class Command1 implements Command {}
class Command2 implements Command {}
```

Comment: Agreed. The advantage you gain from the compiler actually being able to verify that a no-arg constructor exists (vs potentially throwing a runtime exception) far outweighs saving a couple of bytes - if there is even a saving to be had

Comment: Memory hans't really been a problem, I was just wondering if this was correct/optimal, I'm not really that experienced with the topic.
Thank you very much for the answer!